# In a chrome extension on a CKEditor5 instance, how to delete last x characters at caret position before inserting content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ckeditor5

I am working on a chrome extension which replaces abbreviations with expanded text. I am handling a specific case for CKEditor5.
As the CKEditor instance is available only in the background executing a script in world 'MAIN', I execute this script there:

```
function injectScript(text, shortcut) {
    const ckEditorElement = document.querySelector('.ck-editor__editable');

    const ckEditorInstance = ckEditorElement?.ckeditorInstance;

    if (ckEditorInstance) {
        ckEditorInstance.model.change( writer => {
            const insertPosition = ckEditorInstance.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();

            const selectionAttributes = ckEditorInstance.model.document.selection.getAttributes();

            // Delete the last `shortcut.length` characters before inserting content

            ckEditorInstance.model.insertContent( writer.createText( text, selectionAttributes ), insertPosition );
        });
    }
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to delete the abbreviation before inserting the expanded text.

For example: if I write `//brb` I want to remove that abbreviation and replace it with `be right back`. Currently I get something like `//brbe right back` as I haven't figured out how to delete it.

I tried using this function on the model that I found in the documentation
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_model-Model.html#function-deleteContent but I can't figure out if this is the right function for this and how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

```
const startPosition = insertPosition.getShiftedBy(-shortcut.length);

const range = writer.createRange(startPosition, insertPosition);

const selection = writer.createSelection(range);

ckEditorInstance.model.deleteContent(selection);
```

1. Clone a position at the start of the abbreviation by using `getShiftedBy`
2. Create a range using those two positions
3. Create a selection using the range
4. Pass the selection to `deleteContent` function on the model.